# Notification importance always Medium for foreground service

Tags: android, service, android-8.0-oreo

I have read that notification importance for foreground services should be at least LOW, but when I try to change importance to LOW or HIGH it is being ignored and notification remains at MEDIUM importance. Why and how can this be fixed?

Code snippet:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            String id = SYNC_CHANNEL;
            String name = getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.sync_data);
            String description = getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.sync_progress);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW; // Setting importance

            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            channel.enableLights(false);
            channel.enableVibration(false);

            if (notificationManager == null) {
                return;
            }
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

            NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), id);
            b.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_refresh)
                    .setContentTitle(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.sync_data))
                    .setOngoing(true);

            startForeground(1547, b.build());
```

Comment: Did you got any solution?